# IE & Firefox web font rendering issues

Tags: firefox, fonts, internet-explorer-8, webfonts, google-webfonts

Has anyone else noticed that Firefox & IE (at least IE8) has issues rendering some fonts at certain sizes where it will fill the "hole" in the `a` character for example.

Chrome & Opera display them fine.

Here is an example:

Chrome @ 14px - Roboto Bold

[image]

Firefox @ 14px - Roboto Bold

[image]

Notice how the `a` character has it's "hole" filled up!?

It appears this is primarily an issue with `14px/15px` font sizes as the issue goes away when using `13px` or `16px`; at least in Firefox.

It is also not restricted to the `Roboto Bold` font; I have seen this issue in other web fonts as well.

Does anyone know if there is a fix to this or is this just a bug in Firefox/IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of a much bigger problem, each browser has its own set of algorithms for doing font rendering.

Here's an article from Smashing Magazine: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/ on this topic.